# two negative clauses

Tags: negation

I want to ask a question regarding combining 2 negative sentences into 1 sentence.

1. It does not reduce variance of the distribution
2. It does not distort distribution of the data

How should I combine them?

a. It does not reduce variance of the distribution and distort distribution of the data

b. It does not reduce variance of the distribution and not distort distribution of the data

c. It does neither reduce variance of the distribution nor distort distribution of the data

d. Other

Thank you

Comment: I'd say: distribution variance and data distribution. It's better technical English.

Comment: No problem. I know it can get hairy trying to stack up nouns as adjectives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest solution is:

> > It neither reduces variance of the distribution nor distorts distribution of the data.

Option (a) is ambiguous. It might indicate one or the other.

Option (b) is clumsy and unidiomatic.

Option (c) is possible but not as neat as the suggested answer.